Change mocked object class name in mockery
I am mocking the laravel request object and I need to modify the mocked object name from Mockery_3_API_V2_Custom_Requests_DestroyRequest to DestroyRequest. How is it possible?
 protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->model = Mockery::mock(MyModel::class)->makePartial();

        $this->destroyRequest = $this->mockRequest(DestroyRequest::class);
    }

    private function mockRequest(string $requestClass)
    {
        $request = \Mockery::mock($requestClass);
        $request->shouldReceive('model')->andReturn('MockedModel');

        $request->shouldReceive('setModel')
                           ->once()
                           ->with($this->model);

        return $request;
    }


It's not supported by Mockery as default but you can do it with __toString() method. I provide update code for it.
protected function setUp(): void
{
    parent::setUp();
    $this->model = Mockery::mock(MyModel::class)->makePartial();

    $this->destroyRequest = $this->mockRequest(DestroyRequest::class);
}

private function mockRequest(string $requestClass)
{
    $request = \Mockery::mock($requestClass);
    $request->shouldReceive('model')->andReturn('MockedModel');

    // Mock the __toString method to return the desired name
    $request->shouldReceive('__toString')->andReturn('DestroyRequest');

    $request->shouldReceive('setModel')
           ->once()
           ->with($this->model);

    return $request;
}


It didn't work. I tried $this->assertSame(class_basename($this->destroyRequest), 'DestroyRequest'); and it's false
